# How to customize the ember-cli-pace loader in ember application?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I installed ember-cli-pace addon into my ember application, want to change the default loader.

But not getting How and from I should change it.

I am using ember-cli with version 1.13.8

Comment: After searching this I found the way for adding loader for ember application.
Just go through following steps.
1. goto into your project dir using command line
2. execute the command: bower install pace
3. import the required pace.js file and theme.css file into ember-cli-build.js file
4. execute the command ember serve.
that's it.
If their is any suggestion or problem on this are welcome.